# What is pull_interval in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What is `pull_interval` in neo4j?

We are using neo4j HA clustering and there are one master and two slaves. By default `pull_interval` is disabled/commented where slaves are sync instantly. When we enable and change this value to `pull_interval=60`, It doesn't affect anywhere.

Refer neo4j.conf:

```
ha.pull_interval=60
ha.tx_push_factor=2
ha.tx_push_strategy=round_robin
```

How can I make 60 seconds lag in slave from master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transactions are propagated from Master to Slave nodes in an HA cluster through both `ha.pull_interval` and `ha.tx_push_factor`.

The reason you aren't seeing lagging is because your push factor is 2, so when a transaction commits, the Master will attempt to replicate that transaction to 2 slaves. If those attempts are always succeeding, then you wouldn't see a lag in the slaves since they're always up to date.

If you set the push factor to 0, then the master will not attempt to replicate transactions to the slaves, and then the pull interval will become important, as only then will the slaves catch up to the master.

Obviously there's danger here, for if the Master goes down before the slaves can catch up to it, then there's a chance data may be lost.